# How to build text to video and create AI avatar speaking the text?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, ai-design, transformer

There are so many text-to-video tools available online like synthesia ai, elai io. I like to build project like this. Can anybody tell how does these built and how it works?

I know the basics and know ML classification and regression models, but need some knowledge on this. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)